# Component does not render despite its visible in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling with injecting data which comes from async function into render. I managed to fetch data from async function *get_news* and set it to state in order to use it in future in html render. Fetched code which creates instance of component 'News'  is visible only in 'inspector' html code in browser, but not on the "classic view" in browser itself. I am assuming that this resolution is bad, maybe some of you can suggest another mechanism or quick fix for this existing one.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import News from "../components/News";
import {get_news} from '../web3integration';

class Browser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={news: "empty"};
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    var data= await get_news(0);
    var news = "<News title=\"" + data[3] + "\" owner=\"" + data[1] + "\" content=\"" + data[4] + "\"></News>"
    this.setState({newsy:news});
  }


  render() {
      return <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.newsy}} />
      </div>;
      
    };
  }

export default Browser;
```

Answer (score 0):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is only there to produce HTML - as its name says! It isn't designed to take a string representing arbitrary JSX code and render those React components.

In any case, as the name says, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is dangerous and should almost never be used. It's totally unnecessary here even if your approach did work. Just render the component itself and pass it props which come from the state which you update in the async function:

```
class Browser extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // I would never actually write the below code but without knowing what get_news returns I'm just going off what's implied in your original code where you tried to use it to set props of News. In practice you probably want an object rather than array to hold these values.
    this.state={news: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]};
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    var data= await get_news(0);
    var news = "<News title=\"" + data[3] + "\" owner=\"" + data[1] + "\" content=\"" + data[4] + "\"></News>"
    this.setState({news: data});
  }


  render() {
      return <div>
        <News
          title={this.state.news[3]}
          owner={this.state.news[1]}
          content={this.state.news[4]}
        />
      </div>;
      
    };
  }
}
```